# Using Discord.js, is there a way to ban a user who is not in the current guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a bot with moderation features and I haven't been able to find any way to ban a user other than `member.ban()`. This works fine when the user is actually in the guild, but when they aren't it doesn't work. I know this is possible since I've seen other bots (mee6 for example) do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes.

---

You can ban a member using [`GuildMember.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban), just like you said in your post.

If the user is not in your server, you can not use the above method. The solution is simple.

You can use [`GuildMemberManager.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=ban), which takes a [`UserResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable). It can be a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), or even just a [`Snowflake`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake) (ID).

---

Simple Example:

```js
message.guild.members.ban("12345678901234567");
```